# How to run multiple anonymous struct in one file?

Tags: go, struct

I have an anonymous struct with the usage in an HTML template like this

```
sm := struct { Success string } {Success: "Your account is successfully created"}
tmpl.Execute(w, "signup.html", sm)
```

But then I have another struct with the usage in the same HTML template

```
fm := struct { Failure string } {Failure: "An account is not created")
tmpl.Execute(w, "signup.html", fm)
```

When I run the code, it runs the first `struct` but when the account is not created, it does run the second `struct`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple if statement to accomplish this.

```golang
err := whateverYouUseToCreateAccount()

if err != nil {
    sm := struct { Success string } {Success: "Your account is successfully created"}
    tmpl.Execute(w, "signup.html", sm)
} else {
    fm := struct { Failure string } {Failure: "An account is not created")
    tmpl.Execute(w, "signup.html", fm)
}
```

Noted that you might want to alter your template html a bit to combine `.Success` and `.Failure` into one `.Message`, so that you can do this:

```
type SignupResponse struct { Message string }

err := whateverYouUseToCreateAccount()
var sr SignupResponse

if err != nil {
    sr = SignupResponse{ Message: "Your account is successfully created"}
} else {
    sr = SignupResponse{ Message: "An account is not created")
}
tmpl.Execute(w, "signup.html", sr)
```